Sunlight intensity, temperature and lens flare
1- How can I calculate the sunlight intensity in percentage? (without external influences such as clouds or pollution).
In this site SunCalc, Solar constant changes from location to site or from time to time throughout the day,Why does this happen and does it need to be calculated every time to calculate solar irradiance?
2- How can I calculate sunlight temperature in Kelvins?
And what are the constant values throughout the day for (sunrise, sunset, golden hour and noon)? And is it related to the sun's altitude or time?
3- At what degree of the sun's altitude does it's lens flare appear?

one way could be assume sun as a perfect black body and apply wein's displacement law to it, it would at least provide you with an upper limit of how high could be its temperature at max

Lots of questions here, and normally it is better to just as one. But it seems that your set of questions are all about one thing: how does the sunlight intensity and spectrum change over the day? That has some answers. Preetham, Shirley, and Smits (1999): "A Practical Analytic Model for Daylight" might be a start.
